# JavaScript Not Sending Info To WebSocket When Page is Loaded

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I am having trouble sending information of a session cookie when loading a page.

Here is how the function executes

```
<body onload="example();">
```

Here is the function it self

```
function example() {
  websocket.send("<?php print($_SESSION['example']) ?>")
}
```

I've tried this way as well, but still does not work.

```
function example() {
  websocket.send("Test")
}
```

I also tried calling this function when a button is clicked and it does work.

I was thinking maybe the connection to the websocket is not fast enough and the `example();` function is called before the connection is established. Please let me know how I can make this work.

Comment: No not at all, I tried in different computer and does not tell me anything.

Comment: @waynewhitty what do you recon? Do you think its something to do with the connection being established after the function is executed?

Comment: How are you connecting the websocket?

Comment: @Kiewic the with new WebSocket,I don't think it has nothing to do with the way am connecting. 

`var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://host");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the connection stablish after the execution of the function so what I simply did was `setTimeout`, even duh its not a good practice, it will be enough for the project am doing. Here is short version of my solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           function example() {
               function sendUser() {
                setTimeout(
                   function() {
                   websocket.send("Wroked!")
                   }, 1000);
                }
           }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="example();">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

This a complete example of how to connect to a WebSocket from the `onload` document event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>WebSocket Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function example()
    {
        // open websocket
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80');

        socket.onopen = function() {
            console.log("onopen!");
            // Web Socket is connected. send an initial random message.
            socket.send("Hello!");
        };
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="example();">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The connection to the socket is not within a function, I have tried this way too, where all my code would be inside one function. Any other ideas?

Comment: How do you know your WebSocket is already connected by the time example() executes? There must be some sort of output, double check the JavaScript console.